# How to achieve twitter like push notification via AWS SNS?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, mobile, push-notification, amazon-sns

Is there a way to  achieve twitter like push notification via AWS SNS?

SNS send notification to the user when something is happen him or her?

As i know the best way is to create a topic per user.

When user relate event happened,we publish a notification to the topic.

As AWS described the max topic number is 100,000 per account currently.

What if i've 1,000,000 users, it will not work.

Is there a more scalable scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beeth0ven,

SNS supports publishing to a Topic of subscribed device endpoints or direct publishing to individual endpoints. In your case, you'll want to implement direct publishing to each individual endpoint. This allows more control and personal engagement but also means that you'll need to manage those endpoints in your own database and associate each endpoint to a user of your mobile app. Instead of publishing to a TopicArn, you'll publish individual messages to a TargetArn, which is the SNS Platform Endpoint that represents an app and mobile device. TargetArn is also the same call to send an SMS message to an individual phone number.

SNS Publish CLI: (see --target-arn)
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/publish.html

Direct Publishing via the Console:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-directmobile.html